# Calling a function based on class and modifying inner ids

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.tagform').submit(function() {
            $('#tagsubmit-???').toggle('1000');
            return false;
});
```

And I have many `<form>` elements with the class `tagform`.

```
<form class="tagform" id="tagform-1">
    <ul id="myTags-1"></ul>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="tagsubmit-1" class="tagsubmit" />            
</form>

<form class="tagform" id="tagform-2">
    <ul id="myTags-2"></ul>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="tagsubmit-2" class="tagsubmit" />            
</form>
```

I placed the question marks so you can better understand what I'm trying to do.

How can I tell which form was submitted if my `submit()` function is called based on the class and not the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to know what form was submitted you can use $(this) to get the element, then get the id through .attr().

If you need to get the button within the form you can select the input type submit under the submitted form, like this:

```
$('.tagform').submit(function() {            
        alert($(this).attr('id'));

        $("input[type=submit]", $(this)).toggle(1000); // or $(".tagsubmit", $(this)).toggle(1000);

        return false;
});
```

Or even using .find:

```
$(this).find(".tagsubmit").toggle(1000):
```

More Info:

[Using $(this) selector](http://usingjquery.com/2010/10/using-jquerys-this-selector/)
[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `id` of the element raising the event by grabbing it via `attr`

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

In this scenario though you don't need the id.  You can just use `$(this).toggle` directly because `this` will be set to the DOM element which raised the event.

```
$('.tagform').submit(function() {
  $(this).toggle('1000');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This works great. How can I toggle another element within that same form rather than the form itself?

Comment: @hoverhand for that you'd probably want to use `$(this).find('...')` to search within that form.